# Counting triples $(a_1, a_2, a_3)$ such that $0\leq a_i\leq 9$ and $a_1+a_2+a_3$ is divisible by $3$

Tags: combinatorics

> $6.$ Let $S = \big \{ (a_1, a_2, a_3) \ \big | \ 0 \leq a_i \leq 9 \text{ and } a_1 + a_2 + a_3 \text{ is divisible by $3$} \big \}$. Then the number of elements in $S$ is
>
> (A) 327 $\quad \quad$ (B) 333 $\quad \quad$ (C) 334 $\quad \quad$ (D) 336

I've tried manually counting each case and removing all the cases that don't follow the constraint but when I get to $a_1+a_2+a_3=21$ there is just too much calculation required, I think there is an extremely straightforward way to do this like a theorem or something, I hope someone here knows
this is my (bad) attempt at it hope it makes sense
[my attempt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k7axU.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to MSE! I've edited your question to use mathjax rather than an image so that future users can search for this question more easily. In the future you should do the same ^_^. As for your question, what have you tried? Do you have any ideas of your own? Are there any tools you think might be useful? Once we have a better idea of exactly where you're struggling, we can help you better

Comment: thanks, yup I've tried to solve it but I'm not able to, I think my method is just redundant and lengthy, I can send the photo of what I tried if that helps

Comment: Can you describe the method that you tried?

Comment: I've edited the question and attached an image of my attempt.... it was all I could come up with lol, does it make any sense? I'm hoping for the solution is in a better method

Comment: You seem to say you counted $a_1+a_2+a_3 = K$ cases for $K = 0,3,6,9,12,15,18$ and then got stuck at $K=21$.  But note the trick of symmetry: replacing $a_i$ by $9-a_i$ converts the cases for counting $K$ into cases for counting $27-K$.  So if you really did all the "small" cases, you are done.  Instead of a photo, sharing the counts you actually did would help Readers respond concerning your attempt being correct or not.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a slick solution:

Fact: A number is divisible by three if and only if the sum of its digits is divisible by three.

Thus $3|a_1+a_2+a_3$ iff $3| a_1a_2a_3$ (with the digits joined together implied). There are $999/3+1=334$ nonnegative multiplies of 3 less than $1000$. So the answer is C

Comment: omfg that's so clever, insane... I think this is how you're supposed to do the question cause its been set up in such a way that is clearly implies this solution damnnn, nice one, thanks

Answer (score 2):

In order for something to be divisible by $3$, it has to have remainder $0$ when divided by $3$ or $0\mod 3$

If you want to add numbers, you can just take their modulus, add those, and then take the modulus of that result. In your case, our sum will be $0\mod 3$ if we are adding

1. $3$ numbers that are $0\mod 3$
2. $3$ numbers that are $1\mod 3$
3. $3$ numbers that are $2\mod 3$
4. $1$ number of each $0,1,2 \mod 3$

The numbers that are $0\mod 3$ are $\{0,3,6,9\}$, the ones that are $1$ are $\{1,4,7\}$, and the ones that are $2$ are $\{2,5,8\}$. From here it is a simple permuation calculation since order of triples matters.